# Is it possible to lock sudo from the command line, without editing sudoers or logging out and back in?

Tags: linux, sudo

When you run `sudo` it won't ask a password for at least 5 minutes after you last ran it. You can change this timeout by adding `Defaults timestamp_timeout=0` to `sudoers` with `sudo visudo`. This also instantly locks it.

My question is if there is a way to do it just once, and without `visudo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with the `sudo` `-K` or `-k` options:

> **-K, --remove-timestamp** 
> Similar to the -k option, except that it removes the user's cached credentials entirely and may not be used in conjunction with a command or other option.  This option does not require a password.  Not all security policies support credential caching.

> **-k, --reset-timestamp** 
> When used without a command, invalidates the user's cached credentials.  In other words, the next time sudo is run a password will be required.  This option does not require a password and was added to allow a user to revoke sudo permissions from a .logout file.
>
> When used in conjunction with a command or an option that may require a password, this option will cause sudo to ignore the user's cached credentials.  As a result, sudo will prompt for a password (if one is required by the security policy) and will not update the user's cached credentials.
>
> Not all security policies support credential caching.